# CORS issue when changing to ES6 import versus require

Tags: node.js, apache, vue.js, cors

My Vue app has a backend with a different url to the front end.

In my backend (node) I am using the cors module.

My app is a standard express app and I was using for example:

```
const express = require("express")
```

Everything was 100% fine.

I then changed to ES6 and used import like:

```
import  express from "express";
```

On my localhost everything is spot on however when I deploy I am getting the cors error as per below. (it was fine with the old javascript)

> blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass
> access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is
> present on the requested resource.

My app.js looks like so:

```
import EventEmitter from "events"
import dotenv from "dotenv"
dotenv.config()
import  express from "express";
import cors from "cors";
import  bodyParser from "body-parser";
import  { dirname }  from "path";
import path from 'path';
import  pool from './routes/connection.js'
import { fileURLToPath } from 'url';
const __filename = fileURLToPath(import.meta.url);
const __dirname = dirname(__filename);

import  chalk from "chalk";
import  cookieParser from "cookie-parser";
import  session from "express-session";

const app = express()

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.use(cors({
  'allowedHeaders': ['sessionId', 'Content-Type', 'Authorization', 'authorization'],
  'exposedHeaders': ['sessionId'],
  'origin': ['https://eccentrictoad.com', 'https://www.eccentrictoad.com'],
  'methods': 'GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE',
  'credentials': false,
  'preflightContinue': false
}));

const emitter = new EventEmitter()
emitter.setMaxListeners(0)

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "/server/public")));

import progressRoutes from "./routes/progressRoutes.js";
import  progressResultsRoutes from "./routes/progressResultRoutes.js";
import userRoutes from "./routes/userRoutes.js";
import updateRoutes from "./routes/updateRoutes.js"
app.use(progressRoutes, 
  progressResultsRoutes, 
  userRoutes, 
  updateRoutes
  );
```

I could simply revert back to the old style of doing it using "require" but I would really like to figure out why it is an issue.

I am deployed on an Apache Server

Comment: I was checking your UI form the URL mentioned, the call to API backend at 'https://www.mytoad.co.za/checkEmail/admin@admin.com' seems to be working fine without CORS error ..

Answer (score 0):

`import dotenv from "dotenv"` should be `import dotenv from "dotenv/config"`. Also remove `dotenv.config()`.

That should do it.